# Date difference between two days in python (migration from JAVA code)

Tags: java, python, date, migration

I have a code in JAVA as :

public class Function1 {

```
public long daysBetween(LocalDateTime dt1, LocalDateTime dt2) {
   
    return timeDiffInGivenUnits(dt1, dt2, ChronoUnit.DAYS) ;
}
public long weeksBetween(LocalDateTime dt1, LocalDateTime dt2) {
    return timeDiffInGivenUnits(dt1, dt2, ChronoUnit.WEEKS) ;
}
public long monthsBetween(LocalDateTime dt1, LocalDateTime dt2) {
    return timeDiffInGivenUnits(dt1, dt2, ChronoUnit.MONTHS) ;
}
public long yearsBetween(LocalDateTime dt1, LocalDateTime dt2) {
    return timeDiffInGivenUnits(dt1, dt2, ChronoUnit.YEARS) ;
}
private long timeDiffInGivenUnits(LocalDateTime dt1, LocalDateTime dt2, ChronoUnit unit) {
    long daysBetween = 0l ;
  
    return daysBetween ;
}
```

}

What can be the python code for this one?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
date1 = datetime.strptime(str('2011-08-15 12:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime(str('2012-02-15'), '%Y-%m-%d')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
r.months or r.years or r.days etc

Comment: But the thing is I want to do it in a way where we are passing date 1 and date2 as input and first individual function for days, weeks and months etc and one function generic for any input (days, week, year ) that user passes?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer you added, you can combine the functions to have generic units, as your 5th function, like below.

```py
class FsFunction:
    def days_between(self, d1: datetime, d2: datetime):
        r = relativedelta.relativedelta(d1, d2)
        return r.days
    def weeks_between(self, d1: datetime, d2: datetime):
        r = relativedelta.relativedelta(d1, d2)
        return r.weeks
    def months_between(self, d1: datetime, d2: datetime):
        r = relativedelta.relativedelta(d1, d2)
        return r.months
    def years_between(self, d1: datetime, d2: datetime):
        r = relativedelta.relativedelta(d1, d2)
        return r.years
    def units_between(self, d1: datetime, d2: datetime, unit):
        if unit=="days":
            return self.days_between(d1,d2)
        elif unit=="weeks":
            return self.weeks_between(d1,d2)
        elif unit=="months":
            return self.months_between(d1,d2)
        elif unit=="years":
            return self.years_between(d1,d2)
        else:
            return None
```